# How to retrieve []bson.M type of map

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, bson, mgo

How to retrieve multidimensional []bson.M type of map

The data in mongo is like

```
"taskData" : { 
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-02-20T21:23:11.903Z"), 
    "Task_content" : "@bob", 
    "Priority" : "2", 
    "owner_Uname" : "alice"
}
```

The code through which i tried to access it

```
var n []bson.M
 e := collection.Find(bson.M{"users."+strconv.Itoa(j)+".user_name" :   r.FormValue("value[userName]")}).Select(bson.M{"taskData.owner_Uname":1,"_id":0}).All(&n)
if e != nil {
   fmt.Println("Error : ",e)
}else{
   fmt.Println(n[0]["taskData"])
}
```

getting output like this

```
map[owner_Uname:alice]
```

I need to access this resultant string with another query.
It is a interface i tried to convert it to simple map 
`newMap :=n[0]["taskData"].(map[string]interface{})`but it gives me an runtime error `interface conversion: interface {} is bson.M, not map[string]interface {}`

```
result := rawData{}
err := collection.Find(bson.M{"user_name":n[0]["taskData"]["owner_Uname"]}).All(&result)
```

Now I want to use it in above query ...
Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance

Edit :-
The data in mongo is like

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("56bf128f5a9a6a0ebfdd5075"),
     "deadLine" : {
       "Start_time" : ISODate("2016-05-24T00:00:00Z"),
       "End_time" : ISODate("2016-05-29T00:00:00Z")
     },
   },
   "taskData" : { 
       "createdOn" : ISODate("2016-02-20T21:23:11.903Z"), 
       "Task_content" : "@bob", 
       "Priority" : "2", 
       "owner_Uname" : "alice"
   },
   "group" : {
      "1" : {
        "grp_name" : "grp"
       },
      "2" : {
        "grp_name" : "secondGrp"
       }
    }
```

That will work me too if it is done with nested struct or map in struct

Comment: Is there a special reason not to use a struct?

Comment: Is it can achieve with nested struct @Markus W Mahlberg

Comment: Of course. ;) I do it all the day.

Comment: Will u please give me a demo

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg waiting for your answer ... Help me please I'm very badly stuck with this.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/border/3489566)

Comment: @RickyA Do you know how to type assert  []bson.M to simple map or string? Or is it possible to create struct dynamically ?

Comment: I wrote a demo below, but I have a few things to note. a) @RickyA gave you a useful link. If you had read it properly, you would have had your solution. b) You are talking to peers, asking for something. "Not helpful" is even dumb for what you want to achieve. If you had described in which way the link wasn't helpful, maybe somebody would have had the motivation to help you further. c) Your example data is syntactically incorrect. Next time, please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I apologise to you both, i'm new with go and mongo, i was frustrated that i could not able to do this, and that is my college project, and i need to submit it tomorrow.. thanks for your help @RickyA and Markus W Mahlberg and sorry once again it will never happen again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll provide you with a general example to help you understand, since SO is not a free coding service, but a platform where peers help each other to take a grasp on the problem.

My approach is not to use **`bson.M`** at all for the returned value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type Baz struct {
    Date  time.Time
    Value int
}

type Bar struct {
    Name string
    Baz  []Baz
}

type Foo struct {
    Owner  string
    hidden int
    Bar    Bar
}

const (
    ds   = "localhost:27017"
    db   = "test"
    coll = "nestdemo"
)

func main() {

    o := Foo{
        Owner:  "me",
        hidden: 1,
        Bar: Bar{
            Name: "funky",
            Baz: []Baz{
                Baz{Date: time.Now(), Value: 42},
            },
        },
    }

    // CHECK ERRORS in production environments
    conn, _ := mgo.Dial(ds)
    defer conn.Close()

    c := conn.DB(db).C(coll)
    c.Insert(o)

    l := &Foo{}

    c.Find(bson.M{"owner": "me"}).One(l)

    fmt.Printf("Loaded data: %+v\n", l)
    fmt.Printf(
        "You got your answer to life, the universe and all the rest at %s: %d\n",
        l.Bar.Baz[0].Date.Format(time.Kitchen), l.Bar.Baz[0].Value,
    )
}
```

You can run this program on you local machine (with the constants adjusted as needed), which should give you an output looking like this:

```
$ go run main.go 
Loaded data: &{Owner:me hidden:0 Bar:{Name:funky Baz:[{Date:2016-02-24 09:00:06.471 +0100 CET Value:42}]}}
You got your answer to life, the universe and all the rest at 9:00AM: 42
```

The entry in the according collection should read something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56cd6306538ba56563bdab76"),
  "owner" : "me",
  "bar" : {
    "name" : "funky",
    "baz" : [
      {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-02-24T08:00:06.471Z"),
        "value" : 42
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

A few things are to note here.

1. I didn't need a single character in my struct definitions to have the structs marshaled to and marshaled from BSON. It was done automagically by mgo [according to the rules described in the docs](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Marshal). However, you *can* customize the behavior of the (un-)marshaling, as described there.
2. Unexported fields (**`hidden`** in this example) take their zero value upon unmarshalling – keep that in mind, it can bite you in the neck.
3. There is no need to use **`bson.M`** to handle your data, which makes life a lot easier – no manual type conversions, for example.

In summary: All you need to do is to create a struct your data can be unmarhaled into. Then you can access the various fields as usual, without string fiddling and alike. That's bit of work, but a rather trivial one, as you can see.

**Note:** The data model you have shown is both syntactically and conceptually incorrect. Setting aside the former for now: It is a very bad practice to have values as keys, as shown in the **`group`** subdoc. This will always force you to deal with string parsing back and forth, making your life with MongoDB as complicated as it can get as a developer.

My above suggestion assumes you will correct that into something like:

```
{
…
  groups:[
    {grp_id: 1, grp_name: "grp"},
    {grp_id: 2, grp_name: "secondGrp"}
  ]
…
}
```

Comment: hat off for the amount of effort you have thrown this cause.

Comment: @RickyA Thank you, Sir. Let's call it a finger exercise?